# Docker Compose Failure in Azure App Service Environment (ASEv3)

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

Within an Azure App Service under an App Service Environment, I have configured a Docker Compose setup using the public Docker Hub as a registry source.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:stable
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '80:80'
```

Unfortunately this fails to deploy, and checking the logs, I see very little output:

```
2021-10-21T19:14:55.647Z INFO - Stopping site XXXX-as__6e65 because it failed during startup. 
2021-10-21T19:15:02.054Z INFO - Stopping site XXXX-as__6e65 because it failed during startup. 
2021-10-21T19:15:11.990Z INFO - Stopping site XXXX-as__6e65 because it failed during startup. 
2021-10-21T19:15:28.110Z INFO - Stopping site XXXX-as__6e65 because it failed during startup. 
2021-10-21T19:17:39.825Z INFO - Stopping site XXXX-as__6e65 because it failed during startup.
```

I'll note that moving to a single container setup (instead of a Docker Compose setup) works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Below are few composing files to setup:

```
services:
  web:
    image: nginx
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:80"]
      interval: 10s
```

You can also deploy and manage multi-container applications defined in Compose files to ACI using the `docker compose` command. All containers in the same Compose application are started in the same container group. Service discovery between the containers works using the service name specified in the Compose file. Name resolution between containers is achieved by writing service names in the `/etc/hosts` file that is shared automatically by all containers in the container group.

We have a good blog related to this, please refer to it, thanks to [docs.dockers](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/aci-integration/#running-compose-applications).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but with error: "Container logs could not be loaded: Containerlog resource of type text not found".

The strange thing is that deploying it as a Single Container type (instead of a Docker Compose type) it works fine.
Also, exactly the same docker-compose works perfectly if you use normal App Service (without Environment).

So I suspect it is an Azure bug.

P.s. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/955528/-application-error-when-using-docker-compose.html